# No handlers could be found for logger "shapely.geos"

Tags: python, shapely, proj

I have the following code to get area of polygon using shapely and pycrs.
I was able to run this code successfully in a jupyter notebook but when I incorporate it into my main code, I had an error show up:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "shapely.geos"
```

Seems like I cannot retrieve the area information of the transformed polygon.
Anybody has any idea why?

```
def getAreaPolygon(polygon, config):
if polygon != 'POLYGON (())':
    wkb = shapely.wkt.loads(polygon)
    #mv = makeValid(wkb)
    try:
        prj_file = config.inputfile.replace(".jpg",".prj")
        print prj_file
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        print("prj files does not exist")
    fromcrs = pycrs.loader.from_file(prj_file)
    fromcrs_proj4 = fromcrs.to_proj4()
    proj = partial(pyproj.transform, pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326'), pyproj.Proj(fromcrs_proj4))

    ##### Code run successful until here.

    projected_area = transform(proj, wkb).area ## error steps
else:
    projected_area = 0.0
return projected_area
```